# Why are interstitial ads sometime showing completely black?

Tags: xcode, admob, ads, interstitial

My interstitial ad implementation is based off the example code. Most of the times ads display fine. Sometimes ads show up as completely black screen. Doing a long press on the screen I'm able to select text that isn't visible because it's black text on a back background. Copying and pasting this text in notes revealed the text says:

Server...
Connecting to Game Server...

This behavior was able to appear on both a iphone xs and iphone xs max. This only happens with a production ad id not with a test ad id. Using the test id - ads display without issue.

Another interesting thing. I was able to exit the ad in the upper right hand side. Because the text was black on black and not visible I pressed the upper right hand side on my iphone xs and iphone xs max when the black ad appeared and it exited out - I'm assuming the x is in the corner - it's just not visible.
Working fine with iphone 7 plus and iphone 6.

I don't know which ad is being served that's causing this issue. Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Note: Using the latest version of Admob SDK 7.63.0
Thanks

Device logs:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/sjuq87ukh64ecvq/%D9%82%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%B3%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AA%20%2005-08-2020%2C%2010-36%20PM.crash?dl=0

Comment: can you capture logs and update your question?

Comment: Device logs: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sjuq87ukh64ecvq/%D9%82%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%B3%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AA%20%2005-08-2020%2C%2010-36%20PM.crash?dl=0

Comment: please update your question with filter from admob / ads. cannot access this file

Comment: Updated, file type can’t be viewed on dropbox. You need to download the file.